# Is is possible to get Facebook to send me an email when someone RSVP's to an event?

Tags: facebook, facebook-events

Since I don't poll my Facebook events page, (i.e., log on every few minutes), I'd like to get notifications when someone RSVPs to an event I administer.

I just looked at the notification section on Facebook and only saw:

Events
 - Invites me to an event
 - Changes the date or time of an event
 - Cancels an event
 - Makes me an event admin
 - Posts on the wall of an event I admin
 - Changes the name of an event to which I was invited

Comment: Hmm, yeah, looks limited... no RSS feed, no IE8 Slices, there is an export (iCal option/email) at the bottom of the page but I don't think it dynamically updates).

Answer (score 1):

Not a very helpful answer, but this is indeed not possible currently. It's probably for privacy reasons, same as when you're not notified of unfriendings.

Additionally (but surely less of a reason), events are often used large-scale and you'd go crazy if you get an email for each of the 300 people attending.

However, there is a slight chance that http://betterfacebook.net/ is of assistance in your case, but I never tried it myself.

Comment: There is no site at betterfacebook.net

Comment: @AlE. There was when I posted this answer. I don't remember its content tho. Maybe it is currently or permanently down or moved.